# jQuery scrollTo a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to make the page scrollto a specific element with an id, and this works well:

```
var $target = $('#people');
var scrolltop = $target.offset().top  - 50;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrolltop }, 'slow');
```

Now, I am trying to get the $target from the url with the `location.hash`, but for some reason it doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
var $target = $(location.hash);
var scrolltop = $target.offset().top  - 50;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: scrolltop }, 'slow');
```

If I check the $target value is correct, but I receive this error:
`Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`.

Any idea why?

Comment: May be you are executing your code before your page is loaded fully.

Comment: Hm. It works fine for me.

Comment: __WARNING__: $(location.hash) is a reflected XSS vulnerability. the jQuery function will create html elements out of the first parameter if it looks like html. Open your javascript console and put in $("<img src=x onerror='alert()'>") for proof of this. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) for an XSS primer

Comment: @DavidWaters yeah $(location.hash) may be dangerous, but I wonder how? isn't `location.hash` supposed to give either blank or result prefixed with #?

Comment: I load this code from the chrome dev tool console, but I get this error.

Comment: @kiran Yep, but at any minute someone will put that as the answer to this question and get OP to remove the hash from the string. Say OP was wanting to select by class not id the correct/vulnerable code would be `$(location.hash.substr(1))`

Comment: @DavidWaters even if someone does `$(location.hash.substr(1))`, it would not simply select dom elements with class, we have to manually prepend a dot for proper result. then won't it throw an error? for my case, $("#<img src=x onerror='alert(2)'>") will throw error.

Comment: Alright dot is neglected by jquery, only hash throws error, thanks @DavidWaters for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bug with another piece of the script, that broke the code that worked correctly.

Anyway, I post the solution if somebody need something similar.

```
if (location.hash) {

  // take the hash from the url
  var sectionUrl = location.hash;


  // disable anchor “jump” when loading a page
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 1);


  // "jump" to the div with the location hash 
  setTimeout(function(){
     $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $(sectionUrl).offset().top - 50
      }, 2000);   

  }, 1000)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space between "-" and "50"

Make it "-50"

Worked to mine, hope your's too.